# How to sum rows in groups then filter rows based on the sum

Tags: postgresql

I want to find the sum and count of all positive values in a table grouped by a `type` column. I am only interested in cases where `sum >= 10` and `count >= 2`

For example,

```
type  |  value 
------+-------
A     | 10
B     | 5
C     | 7
B     | 5
C     | 6
C     | -1
D     | 3
D     | 4
```

I want the result

```
type  | sum  | count
------+------+------
B     | 10   | 2
C     | 13   | 2
```

There should not be a row for `A` because `count` would only be `1`. There should not be a row for `D` because the `sum` would only be `7`. The negative `value` should be completely ignored.

I think the answer should be something like:

```
select type, sum(value) as sum, count(value) as count
from my_table
where value > 0
group by type
having sum >= 10 and count >= 2
```

However I am not sure how to correctly combine all of the relevant conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select type, sum(value) as sum, count(type) as count
from my_table
where value > 0
group by type
having sum(value) >= 10 and count(type) >= 2
```